# Failed to authenticate GitHub

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am using VS Code on Macbook M1. Despite logging in using Github website , whenever I try pulling a repository , I get the failed authentication error

Answer (score 0):

git config --global credential.helper cache

Running the above in VS Code Terminal helped clear the above issue